# Is it possible to show different content based on the date in gatsby

Tags: gatsby

I'm using a combination of contentful and gatsby. I want to create a widget that displays contents based on the day of the year, events in the past that occurred on the day the site is visited.

I understand that Page Queries in graphql accept variables. I was thinking I could pass a value (current date) and get the relevant values.

Considering Gatsby is a static generator and the queries are preloaded, I'm not entirely sure that would work. I'd appreciate any pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You have two options:

1. Rebuild the site every day. This way, the content of your widget will be part of the HTML code that Gatsby builds.
2. Build an external API that supplies the content when your Gatsby site calls for it. The content changes dynamically every day but you don't need to build it every day.